# How to foreach 2 array into one array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

```
var color = ["red", "blue"];

var size = ["s", "m", "L"];

//output will be
var final = [
              {
               id: 0-0,
               val: 'red/s'
              },
              {
               id: 0-1,
               val: 'red/m'
              },
              {
               id: 0-2,
               val: 'red/l'
              },
              {
               id: 1-0,
               val: 'blue/s'
              },
              {
               id: 1-1,
               val: 'blue/m'
              },
               {
               id: 1-1,
               val: 'blue/l'
               },
            ];
```

Above code have 2 array which is color and size, I tried to foreach both array and arrange the array with the output below but i failed to do that. The scenario is like, the **color** have **2** values, and **red** is **[0]** and **blue** is **[1]**, and the **size** have **3** values which is **s is [0]**, **m is [1]**, **L is [2]** . So that i want the result have their own key and the value as the output above. Anyone can help on that? The format will be javascript.

Comment: your output data is not correct javascript syntax.

Comment: Show us your code

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the nested `map()` function. Use `flatMap()` to make array 1 dimensional

```js
var color = ["red", "blue"];
var size = ["s", "m", "L"];

function combineArrays(arr1, arr2){
  return arr1.flatMap((x, i) => 
    arr2.map((y, j) => ({id: `${i}-${j}`, val: `${x}/${y}`}))
  )
}

console.log(combineArrays(color, size))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use reduce alongside foreach:

```js
const color = ["red", "blue"]
const size = ["s", "m", "L"]

const out = color.reduce((a, c, i1) => (
  size.forEach((s, i2) => a.push({ id: `${i1}-${i2}`, val: `${c}/${s}` })), a
), [])

console.log(out)
```

Answer (score 2):

Map every entries from first array to every entries in 2nd array, create the object you want for every possibility, finally you need to flatten the 2D array you have:

```js
var color = ["red", "blue"];
var size = ["s", "m", "L"];

function everyCombinations(arr1, arr2) {
  return arr1.map((val1, id1) => arr2.map((val2, id2) => ({
    id: `${id1}-${id2}`,
    val: `${val1}/${val2}`
  }))).flat();
}

const result = everyCombinations(color, size);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: just saw Maheer Ali's solution with flatMap which is nicer than my solution I think

Answer (score 1):

If you are preferring to use loop -

```
            var testFunc = function () {
                var colors = ["red", "blue"];
                var sizes = ["s", "m", "L"];

                var res = [];

                for (let i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
                    for (var j = 0; j < sizes.length; j++) {
                        res.push({ id: (i + '-' + j), val: colors[i] + '/' + sizes[j] });
                    }
                }

                console.log(res);
            }();
```